# Add custom ringtone option to ColorOS RingtoneManagers ringtone picker

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ringtonemanager, oppo

ColorOS (Oppo) offers the ability to select a custom ringtone from a file with its ringtone picker, but it does not work with my app.

You can see that feature [here](https://youtu.be/8BIdeC1LBn0?si=XKV-wJH6Ky-C7m1G&t=23).

This is the code I'm using:

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Ringtone");

    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I think, I have to set a specific flag, which displays that option.

I've tried all the input options shown on [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/RingtoneManager#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER:kotlin.String), but non of them worked.